# Verb for doping in sports

Tags: word-usage, verbs, american-english

I need to know if as a sportsman can say:

> I am going to dope?

I need to know how (especially) the Americans use the verb *dope*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence is perfectly understandable. To my ear, the most natural use of the verb "to dope" is in the gerund form as in the following examples,

> Mike, are you doping?
>
> The goalie for the US women's hockey team was found guilty of doping.

You certainly can use I dope, you dope, he dopes etc. But it isn't as common in every day language.

In your context I would probably say,

> Should I use steroids? [or whatever more specific drug to which you are referring]

or

> I am going to use steroids.

Answer (score 1):

An athlete, not a sportsman. Though technically synonymous, they're not, not really. Henry Higgins was a sportsman, according to Alfred Doolittle, anyway.

"I am going to dope?" may be wrong depending on the context. It is a question.

"Am I going to dope?" is correct but extremely awkward.

"Would I dope?" or "Should I dope?" (depending on the context) would be more in keeping with standard English.

Comment: Suppose I will have a match next week and I'm talking to one of my close friends; My body is not in its best conditions; I say to my friend: My body is depleted. I guess I can use some new hormones for the coming match. Then I continue in this way: "I am going to dope". How a native would say this sentence to avoid being awkward?

Comment: @A-friend: "I should dope." I guess. Come to think of it, it's an awkward word to begin with, almost an obscenity, among athletes. "I'm going to use [nickname of the drug]" ... "I have no choice but to use [nickname of the drug]" ... "I'm going to pop a couple of [nickname of the drug]" ... etc. Over-the-counter pharmaceuticals used to be popular among hockey players at one point until some idiot suffered a heart attack. "I'll pop a couple of Sudafeds," they used to say. Then the League stepped in and kicked everybody's ass.